# How to pass values to a PHP function via URL?

Tags: php, web-services

I have various functions written inside the class in PHP file, I want to pass the value to function from my browser to check whether it gets inserted in my db.

sample code:

```
<?
 class Chat {
 var $db;
     .
     .  

function Chat() {
    $this->initialize();
}
function insertMessage($text) {
    $text = (string) $_GET["message"];
      . //insert query
      .
  } 
}   ?>
```

I tried with `http://localhost/www/Chat/chat.php/chat.insertMessage?text=%27message%27&[]` but I didn't get any response.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$text = (string) $_GET["message"];
```

with

```
$text = (string) $_GET["text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

like url is  https//:www.projectlibrarydb.com/chat.php?mesg=hellodear

code to access it on method is below

```
<?
 class Chat {
var $msg=null;
 var $db;
     .
     .  

function Chat() {

if(isset($_REQUEST['mesg'])
{
     $this->insertMessage($REQUEST['mesg']);
}
}
function insertMessage($text) {
   var $text =$text;
      . //insert query
      .
  } 
}   ?>
```